# How to have only decimal values in the input - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am doing a system that I need that the input be decimal, like this: `0.000`.

But I can't use type `number` in the `input` because when I type any number, the `step` doesn't work.

I already made a function using `parseFloat` but it doesn't work too.

```js
const value = e.target.value;
const valueParseMilion = parseFloat(value).toFixed(3);
```

With that above, it increments the last numbers and doesn't work for me...

What I want is:

The input starts with `0.000`, when I type number 1 for example, it should be `1.000`.

Or if I type `0.10` it should complete `0.100`

And or if I type `10.000` it should be `10.000` as well.

Can someone help me? It can be any function inside of onChange.

Thanks.